# Why would this search method not be scalable?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallel my search algorithm using openMP,  `vTree` is a binary search tree, and I want to apply my search algorithm for each of the point set. below is a snippet of my code. the search procedure for two points is totally irrelevant and so can be parallel. though they do need to read a same tree, but once constructed, the tree wouldn't be modified any more. thus it is read-only.

However, the code below shows terrible scalability, on my 32-core platform, only 2x speed up is achieved. is it because that `vTree` is read by all threads? if so, how can I further optimize the code?

```
    auto results = vector<vector<Point>>(particleNum);
    auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    double radius = 1.6;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (decltype(points.size()) i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        vTree.search(points[i], radius, results[i]);
    }
    auto t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    double searchTime = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t4 - t3).count();
```

the type signature for `search` is

```
void VPTree::search(const Point& p, double radius, vector<Point>& result) const
```

search result would be put into `result`.

Comment: I can't tell without using a profiler, but if I were to guess your threads are cache clobbering each other.

Comment: @Mgetz, I think on a multi-core machine, each core has its own cache, so the multi-thread code should be able to use larger cache, is that right?

Comment: Platform dependent. You might reasonably expect each core to have it's own L1, but shared L3 (unless you have hyperthreading enabled), and assuming these are cores on the same package, and and and...

Comment: @Alaya: all the caches need to be kept in sync between the CPUs when writes happen (on first approximation). Try giving each thread its own results vector and merge them only when done (if that's possible with your algorithm). [Youtube link to video by Scott Meyers on CPU caches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE)

Comment: @Alaya without knowing the particulars of how your system is configured there is no way to answer this question. It could be that you're spawning threads onto a different NUMA node than the data is stored in. In which case accesses would be horrendously painful.

Comment: @Mgetz , How could I check the NUMA configuration infomation on a RHEL platform? currently, I only know `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @Alaya I would start with the [redhat documentation then](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/48756) I would also consider using the [numa aware allocators](http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa_alloc_onnode)

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be that you are cache ping-pong'ing on the result vectors. I would assume that your "search" function uses the passed-in result vector as a place to put points and that you use it throughout the algorithm to insert neighbors as you encounter them in the search tree. Whenever you add a point to that result vector, the internal data of that vector object will be modified. And because all of your result vectors are packed together in contiguous memory, it is likely that different result vectors occupy the same cache lines. So, when the CPU maintains cache coherence, it will constantly lock the relevant cache lines.

The way to solve it is to use an internal, temporary vector that you only assign to the results vector once at the end (which can be done cheaply if you use move semantics). Something like this:

```
void VPTree::search(const Point& p, double radius, vector<Point>& result) const {
  vector<Point> tmp_result;
  // ... add results to "tmp_result"
  result = std::move(tmp_result);
  return;
}
```

Or, you could also just return the vector by value (which is implicitly using a move):

```
vector<Point> VPTree::search(const Point& p, double radius) const {
  vector<Point> result;
  // ... add results to "result"
  return result;
}
```

Welcome to the joyful world of move-semantics and how awesome it can be at solving these types of concurrency / cache-coherence issues.

It is also conceivable that you're experiencing problems related to accessing the same tree from all threads, but since it's all read-only operations, I'm pretty sure that even on a conservative architecture like x86 (and other Intel / AMD CPUs) that this should not pose a significant issue, but I might be wrong (maybe a kind of "over-subscription" problem might be at play, but it's dubious). And other problems might include the fact that OpenMP does incur quite a bit of overhead (spawning threads, synchronizing, etc.) which has to be weighted against the computational cost of the actual operations you are doing within those parallel loops (and it's not always a favorable trade-off). And also, if your VPTree (I imagine stands for "Vantage-point Tree") does not have good locality of references (e.g., you implemented it as a linked-tree), then the performance is going to be terrible whichever way you use it (as I explain [here](http://cim.mcgill.ca/~mpersson/locality_of_ref.html)).

Comment: the only operation to `result` is like `Point* _p = getP(), result.push_back(*_p)`

Comment: I refactored my code and used `std::vector` to store the nodes, I get some speedup, but not really significant.

Comment: Hi, it seems that you have implemented the `vantage point tree`, after some optimization(by flatten the tree into a breadth first traversal array), the search procedure could achieve linear speedup, however, in my application, I need to deal with moving points, so each round, I have to re-construct the tree, do you have any suggestion about constructing a VP Tree in parallel?